# json_encode with MySQL array

Tags: php, json, output

I'm getting an array with values out of my MySQL and I'm trying to json_encode() it.
Theres no output though, nothing. Just a white screen, no error, nothing. Any ideas?
The array $rows is perfectly filled with values.

```
if (!$connection = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pw, $db))
    die( "Connection not successful.\n" );

$sql_qry = "SELECT * FROM `table`;";
if (!$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_qry))
    echo "Wasn't able to send query: ".mysqli_error($connection)."\n";

while ($rows[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));

mysqli_close($connection);

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: how do you know it's perfectly filled with values?

Comment: Check also web server's log for errors...

Comment: just a hint:set transfer character set to utf8 with 'SET NAMES UTF8'

Comment: I suppose you need to use: `$rows = array(); while ($rows[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) ;` so rows will be initialized properly

Comment: i know its filled with values since i used var_dump($rows) to check it.

Comment: SET NAMES UTF8 - where?

Comment: Gillian Lo Wong was right, just needed mysqli_query($connection, "SET NAMES 'utf8'"); in my code. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Your `while` assignment isn't actually iterating the resultset and assigning the existing rows from your SQL Query to this variable. If you wish to access the entire contents of the returned resultset outside of the scope of your while statement, then you need to walk the resultset and assign each row to an array defined before your while statement's execution:

```
$rows = array();
while ($ret = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
    $rows[] = $ret;
endwhile;

mysqli_close($connection);

echo json_encode($rows);
```